# Android: How to restore previous purchased using Android billing 4.0.0

Tags: android, android-billing

I'm trying to create a "Restore" button (just like in iOS) so the user can restore his previous purchases. I'm using the code below, but `List<Purchase> list` comes back empty. I made a real purchase with a credit card, then I delete the app and reinstall from the Google Play Store, but I can't get it the "Restore" button to work. Here is the code I'm using for my "Restore" button:

```
private void restorePreviousPuchases () {

    billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchasesResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {

            if (list != null) {

                for (Purchase purchase : list) {
                    ArrayList<String> skus = purchase.getSkus();

                    if (skus != null) {
                        for (String sku : skus) {
                            setPurchasedItem(sku);

                        }
                    }

                }

            } else {
                Log.d("DEBUGGING...", "onCreate: NULL purchaseList" );
            }
        }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Try this lib. instead https://github.com/akshaaatt/Google-IAP

Comment: I'll check. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same issue. After investigating a bit, it seems that this is a known bug.

However, if you initiate your billing client first and then call queryPurchase it works. Just don't put this inside the oncreate (didn't work for me).

BillingClient billingClient;

```
    public void setupBillingClient(){

     billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mContext)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    startConnection();
}

public void queryPurchases(Boolean consume){

        if (billingClient!=null) {
            billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchasesResponseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                                consumePurchase(list.get(i));
                            }
                    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: ' Just don't put this inside the oncreate', u mean the setupBillingclient? and StartConnection?, if yes do you mean i should call the setupBillingClient when the onclick happens?, please also refer to my question im having the same exact issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791088/purchaseupdatelistner-returning-null-list-of-purchase